# C# Bound library method doesn't accept implementation parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, snapkit, xamarin.ios-binding

Trying to implement the new SnapChat Creative Kit in Xamarin.iOS, I bound the SDK framework using Objective Sharpie. While following the official documentation (which only has implementation steps for swift and obj-c) for other SDKs wan not a problem - I successfully implemented Login Kit - I came to a stumble with this code while trying to send the content to SnapChat.

In particular, in the  [Documentation](https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/creative-kit/#ios), to send the contents to the api, this code is used:

```
// swift

let snapImage = /* Set your image here */
let photo = SCSDKSnapPhoto(image: snapImage)

let snap = SCSDKSnapPhotoContent(snapPhoto: photo)

let api = SCSDKSnapAPI(content: snap)
api.startSnapping({ (error: Error?) in
/* Error handling */
})
```

According to the docs,

> SCSDKPhotoSnapContent is an implementation of the SCSDKSnapContent protocol. It provides a way to model a photo Snap for sharing to Snapchat.

Here is my C# implementation:

```
var snapImage = GetCurrentScreenImage();
SCSDKSnapPhoto photo = new SCSDKSnapPhoto(snapImage);
SCSDKPhotoSnapContent snapPhoto = new SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(photo)

SCSDKSnapAPI api = new SCSDKSnapAPI(snapPhoto);
api.StartSnappingWithCompletionHandler((NSError error) =>
{
    // Error handling
});
```

The problem is SCSDKSnapAPI constructor only accepts SCSDKSnapContent, which is an abstract class, and not its implementation, and I get an error calling it:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SCSDKCreativeKit_Bindings.SCSDKPhotoSnapContent' to 'SCSDKCreativeKit_Bindings.SCSDKSnapContent'

EDIT:

ApiDefinition.cs

```
[Export("initWithContent:")]
IntPtr Constructor(SCSDKSnapContent content);
```

I tried adding another constructor like this:

```
[Export("initWithContent:SCSDKPhotoSnapContent")]
IntPtr Constructor(SCSDKPhtotoSnapContent content);
```

The code now builds, but I receive the following error code from SnapChat on callback:

> SnapEncryptionMetadataUnexpectedStatusCode

Comment: can you provide the code in ApiDefinition.cs?

Comment: Added the constructor code. Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to correctly implement SCSDKSnapContent in Xamarin.iOS. I did find a workaround, that sort of works. If you change constructor for SCSDKSnapAPI in the binding library from SCSDKSnapContent to one of its implementations (SCSDKPhotoSnapContent in my case), like this:

```
[Export("initWithContent:")]
IntPtr Constructor(SCSDKPhotoSnapContent content);
```

You can then correctly call SCSDKSnapAPI in Xamarin

```
var snapImage = GetCurrentScreenImage();
SCSDKSnapPhoto photo = new SCSDKSnapPhoto(snapImage);
SCSDKPhotoSnapContent snapPhoto = new SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(photo)

SCSDKSnapAPI api = new SCSDKSnapAPI(snapPhoto);
api.StartSnappingWithCompletionHandler((NSError error) =>
{
    // Error handling
});
```